# Firebase Storage Promise Not Being Resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I wrote code that retrieves urls of images stored in my Firebase Storage bucket and loads them in an `imageUrls` array.

The code works in about 80% of instances, but for the remaining (seemingly random 20%), when the code is run, it fails to resolve some promises, but doesn't throw an exception either.

**Code:**

```
async function loadImages() {
    // Load image urls from firebase storage
    Object.values(imageOrder).forEach(async (fileName, index) => { // Iterate through each imageName for image that should be loaded (e.g., "dogs.jpg", "mountains.jpeg")
        const imgRef = ref(storage, `images/projects/${project.id}/draft/${fileName}`)
        const imgUrl = await getDownloadURL(imgRef) // this promise may never get resolved for some iterations of the loop
        const imgPos = index // store index in array at which this image should be inserted into

        setImageUrls(prevState => {
            let newArray = [...prevState]
            newArray = newArray.map((item, index) => index === imgPos ? imgUrl : item) // replace null value in array with loaded image url at appropriate index
            return newArray
        })
    })
}
```

The promise that never gets resolved appears above in the line `const imgUrl = await getDownloadURL(imgRef)`.

I inserted console log statements at various places to understand the details of what is happening. All image names I expected are iterated through in the `forEach` loop, and an `imgRef` reference is created for each.

In some cases though, only a subset of the promises get resolved. In the rest, the code after the `await` statement does not get called, and therefore the resulting `imageUrls` array contains a combination of url strings as well as `null` values.

Why may this be happening? Is there anything else I can do to clarify the problem further? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running those `getDownloadURL()` promises at once using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
async function loadImages() {
    // Load image urls from firebase storage
    const promises = [];
    
    Object.values(imageOrder).forEach(image => {
        const imgRef = ref(storage, `images/projects/${project.id}/draft/${fileName}`);
        promises.push(getDownloadURL(imgRef));
    })

    const urls = (await Promise.all(promises)).filter(url => !!url);

    setImageUrls(urls);
}
```

> Returned values from `Promise.all()` will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order.

So you shouldn't need to explicitly sort using `index`. Also the `filter()` at end removes any `null` values.

Also checkout: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, particularly the pointer to the thread at the bottom. I cannot use `Promise.all` in my instance, because I also need to track the returned url for each `fileName` individually so that I store the key value pair in a dictionary for later use. The link did point to a straightforward solution though which was to replace `forEach` with standard `for` loop. Thanks!